# COUNTIF() for non-contiguous ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use COUNTIF function for non-contiguous ranges. I have used the following formula and it works.

**=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"Z65";"Z66";"Z68";"Z71";"Z72"});"2"))**

However, it is not using cell reference. Therefore whenever I am adding an additional row then I have to change it manually. Is it possible to use COUNTIF() for non-contiguous ranges with cell reference?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to add INDEX and SEQUENCE:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(INDEX(Z65:Z1040000;SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Z65:Z1040000))));2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for yours answer. However, I don't have the option to use additional column (Column E) as you did because in my excel I have lot od data. Is it possible to calculate it without using additional column?